# Disable CTRL-SHIFT-U on 18.04.2. I uninstalled ibus and the combo still works?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, ibus, intellij

I'd like to disable `CTRL-SHIFT-U` on 18.04.2.

Currently, pressing `CTRL-SHIFT-U` within a text prompt will make an underlined `u` appear on the screen and pressing keys will not append text to the prompt until Escape or Enter is pressed.

This prevents me from using the default combo in IntelliJ IDE to toggle case, and I do not wish to use something else than the default.

**There are countless questions about this on Superuser and Askubuntu.** I tried most of the answers, none of them has any visible effect.

> Go to Language Support > Keyboard input method system > Set the value to *none* (some answers suggest pressing the Apply System-Wide button)

or

> Add `export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MOVE=1` to *~/.profile* and then reboot

or

> Kill the *ibus-daemon* process

This one, the process does exist, but it respawns immediately when killed.

Throughout the answers it was implied that ibus was responsible for this behavior. There is even a GitHub issue about this. So I finally caved in and decided to try removing the `ibus` package by using `apt-get remove ibus` and `apt-get purge ibus`, which is suggested by one of the answers.

After rebooting, `CTRL-SHIFT-U` **still** does this thing. There is no longer any *ibus-daemon* process even after startup. If I go to Language Support, there is no longer ibus as a Keyboard input method system option. It is set to none, and only XIM remains as an alternative.

How come the `CTRL-SHIFT-U` still works even after ibus is uninstalled, and how can I disable it once and for all on Ubuntu 18.04.2?

Comment: FWIW it is activating unicode input, there's ctrl+shift+e for emoji input too, . This [page](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/1944) says you can use `ibus-setup` to change the key sequence. Are you sure ibus isn't running, you'd need to stop it as well as uninstalling (eg reboot or use `sudo systemctl ...`).

Comment: @pbhj Before uninstalling ibus and rebooting, I did try `ibus-setup` and only the emoji key sequence could be changed, I couldn't find where to change the unicode key sequence. Right now, `ibus-setup` results in `command not found: ibus-setup` (and the `CTRL-SHIFT-U` combo is still active).

Comment: Actually, this is curious, I'm on Kubuntu 18.04.1 and I don't have ibus installed either and it all works - in Firefox - for me. Maybe it's your browser or another app that is doing the input management, it doesn't work in the native Kate for me, for example.

Comment: Looks like it's a [Gnome thing](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/commit/66a7da8eb9cecc6fcc646a5f7a32ae9823738584) too, hence why it works in Firefox, and Inkscape for me but not in native KDE apps.

Comment: i am facing the same issue in android studio any solution for the same?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1392682/736624

Answer (score 2):

There is a way Without making system-wide changes which may cause unwelcome side effects. Run IDEA with environment variable `XMODIFIERS` set to empty. There are a few ways to do that:

1. Run IDEA from command line or a script as follows:

   ```
   XMODIFIERS="" /path/to/idea/bin/idea.sh
   ```
2. Edit idea.sh and add the following line at the top:

   ```
   export XMODIFIERS=""
   ```
3. Edit Gnome desktop entry for IDEA at `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-idea.desktop` and precede the `Exec` line like:

   ```
   Exec=env XMODIFIERS="" "/path/to/idea/bin/idea.sh" %f
   ```

Either will do. The last one is for launching IDEA by clicking on its icon from the dock while the others would work from command line too. Just keep in mind if the first method is used with an intermittent script, the desktop entry created by IDEA wouldn't point to this script. So you may want to alter the path at the `Exec` line so it points to your script or use method 2. This method though would need be re-applied each time you install new version of IDEA.

My solution to do it once is:

1. Install IDEA into folder like `some/path/idea/idea-IU-192.6817.14`
2. Run IDEA and create desktop entry for it (menu `Tools`)
3. Link given IDEA version under `current` folder

   ```
   ln -s some/path/idea/idea-IU-192.6817.14 some/path/idea/current
   ```
4. Edit `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-idea.desktop` and change `Exec` line

   ```
   Exec=env XMODIFIERS="" "some/path/idea/current/bin/idea.sh" %f
   ```

Whenever you download a new version of IDEA just link it as `current` and no need to repeat these steps. Obviously extracting new versions of IDEA always to the same folder and replacing the previous version would work as well without linking.

Comment: If IntelliJ is installed as a snap, the desktop entry is located at /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/intellij-idea-ultimate_intellij-idea-ultimate.desktop (I don't know why the name is duplicated) the exec line is then `Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/intellij-idea-ultimate_intellij-idea-ultimate.desktop XMODIFIERS="" /snap/bin/intellij-idea-ultimate %f
`

Comment: this is the best solution. previously, I tried to use solution 2, but can't get any permission. With this solution, no need to change *.sh file. Thanks.

Comment: seems `ubuntu18.04.4` not work

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug listed here:

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1885914

The solution that I found is to remove the ibus package:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ibus
$ sudo apt-get purge ibus
```

Go to updates and set the repository for *focal fossa* version for Ubuntu and remove the remanescent ***eoan***

Go to updates and set the repository for focal fossa version for Ubuntu and remove the remanescent eoan and reinstall ibus:

```
sudo apt-get install ibus
```

Go to language suport and set the iBus method, for user and root

In the terminal for user and root:

```
ibus-setup
```

and change the shortcuts in the emoji tab

In the terminal for user and root:

```
im-config
```

and set ibus

For user in the terminal:

```
gedit .bashrc
```

Include the following lines at the end:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

Comment: The question is about Ubuntu 18.04. Correct me if I'm wrong but your solution is for 20.10?

Comment: Came here looking for a solution on RedHat 8. There is no im-config on my distro but setting the 3 environment variables in the last section above did the trick for me. Thanks! I do have ibus-setup and it is showing all `emoji annotation` and `unicode code point` keys as deleted but until I set the above `ctrl shift U` and `ctrl shift E` were still getting turned into character compositions.

Answer (score 2):

It releated with ibus shortcuts, remove those shortcuts with:

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey "[]"
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji unicode-hotkey  "[]"
```

Comment: i'm on Fedora 36 with Gnome, and neither of these lines work. I executed both of them and still get the underlined u when I do ctrl shift u

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu 20.10 I just open IBUS preference (ibus-setup) and change shortcut at Emoji tab

[window screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9tqh.png)

Comment: Since the question is about Ubuntu 18.04, an answer for 20.10 might not be very useful.

Comment: @ArturMeinild My question is almost 2 years old, I think it's fair to document it as an answer if there's a way to properly resolve it in newer versions